# Oracle r12 - Invoice Voucher Number and Invoice Sequence Number columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ebs

Would anyone know where can I find in Oracle tables Invoice Voucher Number (normally stored on the invoice header level in the payables module) and invoice sequence number?

I have searched far and wide but seem not to be able to find the answer.

Thank you!

Comment: According to [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E51111_01/current/acrobat/122aprg.pdf), you seem to be looking for `AP_INVOICES_ALL.VOUCHER_NUM`, `AP_INVOICES_INTERFACE.VOUCHER_NUM` or `AP_INVOICES.VOUCHER_NUM` ?

Comment: The answer would depend on the application, which you have not told us.  There is no universal set of tables that would be used by all billing applications that run on oracle.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you so much. Those columns actually came blank, but I have discovered that AP.AP_INVOICES_ALL.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE column actually stores what on Invoice header level in the Payables module appears as Voucher Number! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

AP.AP_INVOICES_ALL.DOC_SEQUENCE_VALUE column actually stores what on Invoice header level in the Payables module appears as Voucher Number